# JavaScript only runs when both the code is inside the HTML and is called externally with <script src=...>

Tags: javascript, html, flask, jinja2

My JavaScript code only runs when the code is both inside the HTML file and called externally via

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{  url_for('static', filename='index.js') }}"></script>

<script>
var scroller = document.querySelector("#scroller");
...
</script>
```

I am using Flask and Jinja, with a file structure of:

```
/app
  /static
    index.js
  /templates
    base.html
    myfile.html
  routes.py
  __init__.py
  ...
```

The code inside `index.js` is the exact same code between the `<script>` tags inside the HTML.

In terms of jinja and using block tags, `base.html`:

```
<body>
{% block content %}
<!-- typical HTML stuff here -->
{% endblock %}

<!-- some Bootstrap tags -->
<script ... ></script>

{% block script %}{% endblock %}
</body>
```

`myfile.html`:

```
<body>
...

{% block script %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{  url_for('static', filename='index.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}

<script>
...
</script>
```

The code itself works, and it worked not too long ago without this issue; I don't know what I changed to cause this, nor can I even imagine what could cause this. If there is more code that is required, I can easily share it.

Is there something I not understanding?

*To note: I have had a similar issue trying to including external JavaScript code inside my HTML; at one point it wouldn't work, then it did, now it behaves the way I have described.*

*To further note: I have another `.html` file with its own external `.js` file that works fine.*

Comment: It's not clear what code doesn't work. Is it the external script or the inline script? What exactly is not working, and what does "_work_" in the context of this question even means?

Comment: The entire JavaScript code I have inside `index.js` works, but it only *runs* when it is inside both forms of `<script>` tags.

Comment: I have changed the wording as I agree "run" is better. However, I don't think the wording is actually that big of a deal, as my program doesn't *work* unless I include it both `<script>` tags, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Mr.@JakeJackson, Script in externl file never requires the same content to be available inside your inline code.
May be you are trying to process some elements and your script got executed before those elements are mounted to the document object.

A lazy solution to that problem is moving the external file linking  tag to the bottom your HTML.Body.

OR

You can use **defer** attribute to your script element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

OR

If you have some libraries like jQuery included in your page, You can use the document.ready implementations in that

OR

you can implement your own document.ready like below

```
      function myReady() {
            return new Promise(function(resolve) {
              function checkState() {
                  if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
                    resolve();
                  }
                }
                document.addEventListener('readystatechange', checkState);
                checkState();
          });
        };
        myReady().then(function() {
          // Put your app custom code here
        });
```

Comment: Hi, Karthi. I know I don't need to have the same code inline and externally code; the issue I am having is that my JavaScript code won't run unless I do that though. And sadly, using  `defer` didn't work :( I am not using any jQuery either, and my `script` tag is at the bottom already. Thank you for the help though :)

Comment: Then please try with that myReady function

Comment: Oh, I didn't properly notice that, thought it was jQuery related. I will do now, thanks.

Comment: Sadly no luck :/ I appreciate the help though